# fb.ui feed picture not showing when posting to facebook new design

Tags: facebook

I see this is a common problem that could be caused by several reasons, but I'm not sure this is the case.
My js code to post on the users wall is very simple and straight forward, and has been working so far with no problem (about 6 month in use):

```
FB.ui(
      {
          method: 'feed',
          name: 'some text',
          link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/myapp',
          picture: 'http://mydomain.com/content/images/theimage.png?v=123',
          caption: 'my caption',
          actions: [
            { 'name': 'Play now' , 'link': 'https://apps.facebook.com/myapp' }],
          description: 'my description',
          ref: 'my ref'
      },
      function (response) {
      }
    );
```

I've recently switched my Facebook account to the new design (2013), and on my feed these publishes appear without the image.
checking from another account running the previous design, these publishes shows correctly with the correct image.

so, it's not Facebook cache, and it's probably not my code. is it a Facebook bug? any other ideas?

thanks!

Comment: How big is your image? Facebook suggest 600*600px or even higher to get optimal distribution in the new newsfeed. _“The larger this image is, the more likely it will be used when sharing stories on Facebook.”_ – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/maximizing-distribution-media-content/#tags

Comment: @CBroe the image is 90*90px only...but I also tried it with http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg which is 390*366px and that also doesn't work.